# How do we get Exchange online to identify Sendgrid messages as TreatMessagesAsInternal?

Tags: smtp, relayjs

Using Sendgrid as an SMTP relay for Exchange in order to avoid the basic auth deprecation.  Currently when Exchange sees a message sent by Sendgrid it identifies it as external sender.  These emails are being sent via internal systems using Sendgrid.  How can we get Exchange to consider them as internally sent?

•   Authenticated mailbox on-prem or Exchange Online (StoreDriver)
•   Authenticated mailbox using SMTP client submission (SMTP AUTH)
•   Received through an on-prem receive connector with ExternalAuthoritative (Externally Secured) permission enabled –
o   (This is what we are currently doing)
•   Came into Exchange Online via an inbound connector with TreatMessagesAsInternal set to “true” and the sender is an accepted domain.
o   I tried this but can’t get it working.
o   It seems you can’t set TreatMessagesAsInternal to “true” if CloudServicesMailEnabled is enabled or if ConnectorType is not OnPremises.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.